# python, if condition on methods

Tags: python, methods, if-statement

i have two methods `New()` and `Edit()` and another method  `make()`  that has some statements.. `New()` and `Edit()` both call `make()`, however there are some statements i would like to skip in `make()` if the calling method is `new()`. Take an example below

```
def new():
 make()


def edit():
 make()


def make():
  statement 1
  statement 2
  statement 3 not to be executed if calling method is new()
```

Is this implementable in Python?

Comment: By the way, those `pass` statements are redundant.

Comment: @detly! Very true, i have removed them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes — put statement 3 in `edit()`.

Alternatively, if you want other things to be able to call `make()` and execute statement 3, use keyword arguments to specify a default behaviour:

```
def new():
  make(skip=True)

def edit():
  make()
  # OR: make(skip=False)

def make(skip=False):
  statement 1
  statement 2
  if not skip:
    statement 3

# Previously written invocations of make() don't have to change now
```